# vim blank line is red and disappears after changing the window size

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]
I am using vim in WSL under Windows and when opening a file this red mark does not appear, once I scroll down the file and then go back up again this red mark appears. If I use the scroll wheel it causes the whole file to turn red, but when I use only the up and down keys it only turns the part that was on top red. But once I change the window size, the red mark disappears.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jun 29 2021 11:09:25)
Included patches: 1-3072
Compiled by root
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +python/dyn        +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xsmp
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lm -ltinfo -ldl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be fixed with setting the t_ut terminal code to nothing at all.

```
set t_ut=
```

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832